# Windows mail showing "content preview" text - how can I turn this off?

Tags: windows-7, windows-mail

All of a sudden Windows Mail has started showing this kind of thing on ALL emails:

[image]

How can I stop it showing this? It's only just started doing it.

Here's another example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any mail server between you and the sender has set up SpamAssassin software wrongly - marking and editing super-positive mails.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out AVG had sneakily updated and started to flag it all. Uninstalled and everything works fine.